# Solace batch publisher is very slow

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

Processor function consumes and publishes messages to solace in batch. Method signature is as below. It publishes each message in the batch as individual messages. TPS observed is around 150.

```
Function<Message<List<String>>, Collection<Message<POJO>>> receiveMessage()
```

**Issue** :

Batch publishing is very slow. For a batch size of 255, it takes more than a second to publish.

**Observation** :

If the method signature is updated as below then the **entire batch is published as a single message**, so down stream consumers cannot consume messages one by one. TPS observed is around 1000. There is a huge performance difference.

```
Function<Message<List<String>>, Collection<<POJO>>> receiveMessage()
```

**Questions** :

The service needs to handle around 2000 TPS (Multiple instances of same service). The service is very simple, just consume, perform minor transformation and publish. Please suggest config options to optimise publish. With batch publish are there any config to avoid acknowledge or round trip for each message?

Thanks

Comment: hi Tilak, my guess is that this performance issue is within the Cloud Stream framework itself. I do not believe that any of the binders know when a Collection of messages are being published and should be done individually. Have you opened an issue in the repo?

Comment: Hi Mrc0113, the Spring cloud stream binder for Solace is from Solace. I have not opened a issue yet, will create one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved by setting property PUB_ACK_WINDOW_SIZE. Default publish window size was 1

Comment: Hi Tilak, may I know how to set the PUB_ACK_WINDOW_SIZE property?
is it set at the spring cloud stream binder or bindings level?
Thanks.